# How is a TFHub module retrained since there is no label used?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is a link to a TensorFlow Hub module: [imagenet/mobilenet_v1_050_160/classification](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/p/products%2F3b2b0bb1-3328-4391-999d-99da1adc16f3/v/3). In the fine-tuning example code:

```
module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v1_050_160/classification/3",
                    trainable=True, tags={"train"})
logits = module(inputs=dict(images=images, batch_norm_momentum=0.997),
                signature="image_classification_with_bn_hparams")
```

it seems that the input only contains the images, no labels. And I managed to get the input information, it turned out that the inputs are only 2 elements: the **input images** and **batch norm momentum**.

So I wonder **How can this module be retrained/fine-tuned without labels input?**

And **I hope someone can tell me how would the batch norm momentum work in this TensorFlow hub module**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`logits = module(inputs=dict(images=images, batch_norm_momentum=0.997),
                signature="image_classification_with_bn_hparams")`

this above part consists of class labels as indices. You can read about it [here](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2F3b2b0bb1-3328-4391-999d-99da1adc16f3/v/3) inside **Usage**.

> The indices into logits are the num_classes = 1001 classes of the classification from the original training

Comment: My goodness, I'm not an ML guy so it is my first time to hear about such a thing. Is this a kind of practice popular in ML? After re-reading the sentence you point out, I still don't think this sentence can be explained in your way. Why doesn't the author just simply use a much more straight-forward expression? And if you are right, how to deal with this problem: train multiple images of just one class at the same time?